# Отправка почтовых писем через smtp Яндекса

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток, давно ищу простой и понятный код для отправки писем через smtp. Везде где не искал, предлагают или огромную библиотеку по типу phpMailer или вообще старые варианты, которые уже не работают.

Хотелось бы увидеть простой код, который просто отправляет текстовое сообщение вида:

```
smtpmail('Посетителю', $_POST['email'], 'Код для завершения авторизации', 'Ваш код для завершения авторизации: 1234.);
```

Главное что-бы все работало через авторизацию и SSL. Собираюсь использовать SMTP Яндекса через сокет. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Есть отличный класс [SendMailSmtpClass](https://vk-book.ru/otpravka-pisem-cherez-smtp-s-avtorizaciej-po-protokolu-ssl-na-php/), он состоит всего из одного небольшого файла, работает через сокеты, поддерживает SSL и 100% рабочий.

Вы можете или создать экземпляр класса и работать с ним - как предлагает автор в примерах.

Или возьмите код класса и внедрите в свое решение через функции или как Вам удобнее.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'Exception.php';
require 'SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();

$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';


$mail->Host = 'mail.sentmail.ru';                                                                                             // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'login@sentmail.ru'; // Ваш логин от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->Password = 'p'; // Ваш пароль от почты с которой будут отправляться письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров

$mail->setFrom('login@sentmail.ru', 'name'); // от кого будет уходить письмо?
$mail->addAddress('tomail@sentmail.ru');     // Кому будет уходить письмо 
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML


$bodyMail4=' ';
$filename='mail.ics';
$separator = "---";
$from_name='name';
$from_address="tomail@sentmail.ru";$headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n"; // задаем от кого письмо



$headers .= "MIME-version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .=  "Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$filename\"\r\n"; 

$mail->Subject = $headers;

///$mail->Subject = 'Кто-то оставил форму обратной связи!';
//$bodyMail = " ";
 
$bodyMail = 'text';
//$mail->msgHTML($bodyMail);

$mail->Body = $bodyMail4;

 $mail->addStringAttachment($bodyMail,'ical.ics','base64','text/calendar');
//$mail->AltBody = '';
//$mail->AddAttachment('mail.ics');

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo '<b>Не удалось отправить заявку :(</b><br>Позвоните нам!';
} else {
   echo 'Всё хорошо!';
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]